# JQuery resize handles not working after rotation using jQueryRotate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable, handles

I have a problem with the resizing handles in jquery.

Basically, I have a div dragging, resizing and rotating (using jqueryRotate) as expected. However when the div rotates the handles rotate with it but still maintain the original resizing direction.
In other words, after a clockwise 90-degree rotation the original 'SE' handle is now in the 'SW' position but still resizes when being dragged in the NW-SE direction rather than the NE-SW direction it should now have.

If anyone can understand this question and help,  please do.

Answer (score 0):

I had some contact with the creator of the jqueryrotate plugin.

You can read all about it in this issue:

[Issue Link jqueryrotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/issues/detail?id=57&can=1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That doesn't sound too helpful does it...  Did you find a way to get the rotation to recognise the dragging directions or were you able to find an alternative?  I don't think my javascript/jquery is up to writing my own solution.

Comment: This issue is still bugging me a lot. It seems impossible to do this. The only way i can think of is using css3 or html 5 but that is not fully supported by all browsers.

Comment: I've not found a solution eith.  I have seem a site which has managed to solve this but I'm not sure how they achieved it.